# SQL 2005 Log Shipping - Was working, now isnt!

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2005, logging

I had log shipping working between two SQL 2005 server fine.

I suspect that a job was added to the source server which backed up the transaction log to disk (nothing to do with the existing log shipping job).

As I understand it, if you do this then log shipping will fail to work.

Sure enough, it no longer works.

I've deleted the job which had just been created.

Log shipping still does not work.

I've rebooted both servers and, again, Log shipping does not work.

I'm at a loss now... all I get is the folloing error:

**The log shipping secondary database XXXXXXXXXX has restore threshold of 45 minutes and is out of sync. No restore was performed for 5882 minutes. Restored latency is 15 minutes. Check agent log and logshipping monitor information.**

Any help appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you have added the tlog bkp in between your sequence of tlog on log shipping got disturb.

The quickest workaround is
start your full backup and restore that full backup (Jobs) and then tlog will take from there.

*Hope you have removed an extra tlog backup.

Answer (score 1):

Vinay is right on the money on how to fix the problems, there are a few things that will break log shipping:

- Bad LS config (but then it won't ever work)
- Log backup outside of the LS job that doesn't follow the same naming convention or back up to the same location
- Changing the recovery mode of the database to SIMPLE from FULL, even if you put it back

To fix the problem simply take a full backup and restore it to LS secondary and then let the LS jobs catch up the log files, but you need to find the process/person that broke the log chain to fix the problem for good.